# How to define a marginal area for mouse events?

Tags: javafx, event-handling, mouseevent, contextmenu, linechart

Is it possible to capture **mouse events** on a specific **JavaFX node** and also inside a **marginal area** around it? If yes, how can I do it?

For example, I want to call the `setOnContextMenuRequested()` method when a JavaFX `Node` or its marginal area (in pixels) is right clicked.

P.S. If your suggestion is to use a transparent node with the margin size as the parent of my node, I cannot do it. Because my node is actually a `lineChart` point that will automatically connect to others via lines. In this case, this transparent node would make a gap between the line and the point connected to it.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to handle the parent's `onMouseClicked` and check for bounds/collision.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you exactly asked for, but maybe it helps you:

```
yourNodeHere.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                //Define the clickable area
                if(event.getX() > primaryStage.getWidth() - 50
                   && event.getX() < primaryStage.getWidth()
                   && event.getY() > primaryStage.getHeight() - 50
                   && event.getY() < primaryStage.getHeight()) {

                    //Define your action for the clickable area
                    System.out.println("Mouse is in clickable area");

                } else {
                    //Define your action for the non-clickable area  
                    System.out.println("Mouse is in non-clickable area");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The area defined in the code above is in the right-bottom corner of the node.

Btw: If I remember well, I found this code somewhere on stackoverflow a long time ago, so special thanks to the person who contributed this code.